# Python: Set new column value if multiple columns in a dataframe have any value other than one specific string

Tags: python, pandas

First time posting a question from a newbie coder, open to suggestions and improvement.

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe.
The new column for each row should be populated as per the following:

1) 'Unknown' if select columns in that row all contain the value 'None'.

2) The non-'None' value if one of the columns contains such a value.

In the dataset I'm using, there will only be one non-'None' value if any per row, and the column name is the same as the cell value.

I know I could loop through each row to find a non-'None' value in those columns, and if found set the column value to that (else set as 'Unknown'), but I feel like I'm missing something simple to make this work.

I've looked into selecting the value with .loc/.iloc/.at and a few other methods, but I don't feel like I'm getting close.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],
                   'B': ['None', 'B', 'None', 'None'],
                   'C': ['None', 'None', 'C', 'None'],
                   'D': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'D']})

values = ['B', 'C', 'D']

#In the code below, replace the string  'This should be non-None value (B, C or D)' with an expression
df['Letter'] = pd.np.where(df[values].eq(values).any(1, skipna=True), 
                           'This should be non-None value (B, C or D)', 'Unknown')
print(df)

   A     B     C     D     Letter
0  None  None  None  None  Unknown                                  
1  None  B     None  None  This should be non-None value (B, C or D)
2  None  None  C     None  This should be non-None value (B, C or D)
3  None  None  None  D     This should be non-None value (B, C or D)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df['Letter'] = df.ne('None').dot(df.columns).replace('', 'Unknown')
#if None are not strings
#df['Letter'] = df.notna().dot(df.columns).replace('', 'Unknown')
#oldier pandas versions
#df['Letter'] = df.notnull().dot(df.columns).replace('', 'Unknown')
print(df)
      A     B     C     D   Letter
0  None  None  None  None  Unknown
1  None     B  None  None        B
2  None  None     C  None        C
3  None  None  None     D        D
```

**Explanation**:

Get boolean mask of no `None` values by comparing by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`) or [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) :

```
print(df.ne('None'))
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False   True  False
3  False  False  False   True
```

Then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names:

```
print(df.ne('None').dot(df.columns))
0     
1    B
2    C
3    D
dtype: object
```

And last replace missing values by [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
print(df.ne('None').dot(df.columns).replace('', 'Unknown'))
0    Unknown
1          B
2          C
3          D
dtype: object
```

Another solution :

```
df['Letter'] = df.replace('None', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna('Unknown')
print(df)
      A     B     C     D   Letter
0  None  None  None  None  Unknown
1  None     B  None  None        B
2  None  None     C  None        C
3  None  None  None     D        D
```

**Explanation**:

First [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) strings `None` to missing values if necessary:

```
print (df.replace('None', np.nan))
    A    B    C    D
0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 NaN    B  NaN  NaN
2 NaN  NaN    C  NaN
3 NaN  NaN  NaN    D
```

Forward fill missing values:

```
print (df.replace('None', np.nan).ffill(axis=1))
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    B    B    B
2  NaN  NaN    C    C
3  NaN  NaN  NaN    D
```

Select last column by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.replace('None', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
0    NaN
1      B
2      C
3      D
Name: D, dtype: object
```

And last replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df.replace('None', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna('Unknown'))
0    Unknown
1          B
2          C
3          D
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: I had more columns in the actual DataFrame I was using so I used the second solution successfully. Thanks very much for your help and the easy to understand explanations!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item!='None'][0] if len([item for item in x if item!='None'])>0 else 'Unknown',axis=1)
```

but don't...the other solution is way better, i ll just let this one here for you to see how to do it with apply.

Comment: String...it was strings... (and an axis=1)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)